# Browser add on for measuring areas on the page?

Tags: browser-addons

Im trying to see if all the links in my mobile optimised site have the recommended 44px as a hit area.

Currently im doing this by taking a screenshot and measuring it with a graphics program which is making incremental changes slow. Is there a browser add that can show you on the page how large areas are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple addon for measurment is [MeasureIt](http://frayd.us/extensions/measureit/), it's available for `FireFox`, `Chrome` and `Safari`. It shows a simple overlaying square that calculates dimensions of selected area in `pixels`.

Answer (score 0):

[Greenshot](http://sourceforge.net/projects/greenshot/) is another free (and very useful) screenshot utility that displays coordinates and area information in pixels. (I have it mapped to the <kbd>PrtScn</kbd> button on my system -- extremely convenient.)

And IIRC, Chrome's version of firebug (click <kbd>F12</kbd>), shows a ruler bar of some sort. I can't recall how interactive it is though.